# How can I add the activity in Android Sliding Menu which is fragment

Tags: java, android, android-activity, android-fragments

http://www.androidhive.info/2013/11/android-sliding-menu-using-navigation-drawer/

hi all, I have succeeded apply this Android Sliding Menu in my project.
however, how can i add some activity in diffferent page?

In MainActivity, displayView function controls the fragment which i have selected.you can see it only use in `"Fragment fragment = null;"`,so , the CESDemo class is extends Fragment.But i cannot add my activity in the CESDemo, such as onTouch and so on.If i change it to FragmentActivity, it does not allow me for "`ragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.frame_container,fragment).commit();`"

So, how can i apply some activity in different fragment,even i can design the layout but no any activity i can create.

MainActivity.java

```
private void displayView(int position) {
    // update the main content by replacing fragments
    //Fragment fragment = null;
    Fragment fragment =null;
    switch (position) {
    case 0:
        fragment = new CESHome();
        break;
    case 1:
        fragment = new CESAll();
        break;
    case 2:
        fragment = new CESPending();
        break;
    case 3:
        fragment = new CESInProgress();
        break;
    case 4:
        fragment = new CESCompleted();
        break;
    case 5:
        fragment = new CESDemo();
        break;
    default:
        break;
    }

    if (fragment != null) {
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.frame_container, fragment).commit();

        // update selected item and title, then close the drawer
        mDrawerList.setItemChecked(position, true);
        mDrawerList.setSelection(position);
        setTitle(navMenuTitles[position]);
        mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);
    } else {
        // error in creating fragment
        Log.e("MainActivity", "Error in creating fragment");
    }
}
```

CESDemo.java

```
public class CESDemo extends Fragment {

public CESDemo(){}

public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_cesdemo, container, false); 
    return rootView;
}
```

Comment: So do you understand the concept of activity and fragments?

Comment: I know that activity is used to handle some event such as onClick the button, fragments is used to let the layout more user-friendly . Is it right?

Comment: Not all true, actually you can handle event in the fragment too :) (if the button is located inside the fragment)